# Modal window on a form

Tags: php, html, css, email

Is there a way to make a modal window popup when a input is skipped ?

For example, if someone forgets to put in their email, my current php mail file opens a blank page thats says *please enter email*, but I want a modal window (preferably with an image), that says the same thing without leaving my page.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="9;URL=Thankyou.html">
</head>

<?php
    $EmailFrom = "mail@live.com";
    $EmailTo = "mail@live.com";
    $Subject = "REQUEST";

    $Name = check_input($_POST['Name']);
    $Phone = check_input($_POST['Phone']);
    $Email = check_input($_POST['Email'], "Enter a Email");
    $Message = check_input($_POST['Message']);

    if (! preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $Email))
    {
        show_error("E-mail address not valid");
    }

    if ($Email != 'Email')
    {
        $message = "Name: ".$Name;
        $message .= "\n\nEmail: ".$Email;
        $message .= "\n\nPhone: ".$Phone;
        $message .= "\n\nMessage: ".$Message;
        $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

        if ($success)
        {    
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=Thankyou.html">';
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            print ("<b>I'm sorry, there was a technical glitch, please send your email to me@gmysite.com directly.</b>");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Please fill the required fields, thankyou";
    }

function check_input($data, $problem = '')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }

    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Please correct the following error:</p>
    <strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: You would need javascript for that. What do you have so far and where are you encountering any problems?

Comment: There is no problem with the script it works fine. but what happens is that when someone does not put in thier email and hits send the script opens leaves my page and gives the message "please enter email", but what i want is a modal pox to pop-up if the person hits send without the email

Comment: Just send your form via Ajax, and check the answer... If the answer contains error, then you can alert it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions.

The easiest is to add the html5 `required` attribute to the form fields that are required. That will not give you any options for a pop-up with images though, just a warning in modern browsers that the user cannot submit the form until the field is filled in.

To add a global pop-up window on the same page, you would need javascript. Just check if any of the required fields is empty when you submit the form and display your global overlay if there is. You'd have to write it yourself though...

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 standard includes the [`dialog` element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dialog.asp) with a javascript api to open and close it. However, this is not supported cross-browser yet. You always could use the [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill/blob/master/bower.json) tough, which will allow you to use the dialog element before it is supported cross-browser.